# E WTRN0063E: An illegal attempt to commit a one phase capable resource with existing two phase capable resources has occurred

Tags: mysql, transactions, websphere, jta, xa

I have configured User Defined datasource for MySQL database using below.

- WebSphere 8.5
- mysql-cluster-gpl-7.4.6
- mysql-connector-java-5.1.9-bin.jar

Implementation Class in Provider :

- `com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlXADataSource`

However, I get below exception for JTA transaction spanning MySQL and Oracle datasource operation for MySQL datasource.

> E WTRN0063E: An illegal attempt to commit a one phase capable
>   resource with existing two phase capable resources has occurred.

As per docs, MySQL supports XA-transaction, My driver is implementing XADatasource.

Can you confirm what is it that I am missing. 
May be datasource configuration that it is not two phase capable transactional resources?

I have also used `ENGINE=INNODB` to create MySQL table.

Comment: It sounds like you need to configure your datasource to be XA capable on the WebSphere side.  By default, WAS datasource will not implement javax.sql.XADataSource.  See this link (section 8.e) to verify your config is using an XA datasource: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/ae/tdat_ccrtpds.html?cp=SSEQTP_8.5.5%2F1-3-0-23-3-0-7-1

Comment: @aguibert That seems like a plausible reason, so I would just add it as an answer.

Comment: added my comment as an answer so people can find it easier in the future

Comment: Maybe your Oracle is not configured for XA. Make sure that both data sources are using XA drivers.

Comment: Oracle datasource and transactions are working fine. The issue is with datasource connecting to mysql.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need to configure your datasource to be XA capable on the WebSphere side. By default, WAS datasource will not implement javax.sql.XADataSource. 
See this WAS 8.5 documentation link (section 8.e) to verify your config is using an XA datasource:
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/ae/tdat_ccrtpds.html?cp=SSEQTP_8.5.5%2F1-3-0-23-3-0-7-1

Comment: I am not able to find data store helper for mysql database. eg. I am using below one for Oracle com.ibm.websphere.rsadapter.Oracle11gDataStoreHelper

Comment: @Chava you will have to define a custom JDBC provider.  Check out this video for a walkthough (can probably skip to 2:00 for relevant info): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bnTZ83VKPvU

Comment: I have already defined custom JDBC Provider using com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlXADataSource